# Как в инспекторе добавить разрешение?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Как в инспекторе браузера добавить нужное разрешение?
[image: Скриншот]

По умолчанию предустановлены мобилки, планшеты, 1440...Нужно добавить 1920

Спасибо!

Comment: Qwertiy, да, новое устройство действительно добавляется в список различных устройств. Но я хотел уточнить не про устройство, а про конкретные разрешения, которые на скриншоте идут (это не устройства)

Answer (score 0):

В списке устройств нижняя строчка Edit, а в появившемся окне кнопка Add new device.

Comment: Для лисы: Список устройств > `Edit List` > `Add Custom Device`.

Comment: ΝNL993, да, новое устройство действительно добавляется в список различных устройств. Но я хотел уточнить не про устройство, а про конкретные разрешения, которые на скриншоте идут (это не устройства)

Comment: @jenya1995, хм.. подозреваю, что никак.